# Stackoverflow error

Tags: java, stack-overflow

The code given below shows a Stackoverflow error when run.But if I make another class CarChange to create objects of Car ,it runs sucessfully. I am a beginner ,doing this code to understand the importance of upcasting in java.

```
public class Car {

    int i;
    Car[] c=new Car[2];

    Car() {
        c[0] = new Polo();
        i=0;
    }



    void drive(){
        c[i].testdrive(); //the overloaded method in subclasses polo and swift
    }

    void change() {
        if(i==0) { 
            i++; 
            c[i] = new Swift();
        }
    }

    public void testdrive() {
        //overloaded method in subclasses polo and swift
        System.out.println(" test drive car");
    }



//class Tester {
     //main
     Car c= new Car();
     c.drive();
     c.change();
     c.drive();
```

Comment: Using my ESP I'm going to guess that `Polo` is a subclass of `Car` and it's recursively calling the constructor of `Car`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  And please use a consistent and logical form of indenting code blocks.

Comment: @AramKocharyan thank you ,going through it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A stackoverflow usually means you have an infinite loop.

The reason you're receiving this is because you're calling drive from the testdrive method and in that method you're calling drive again.

Comment: i have edited it,I am sorry the code was not clear but testdrive() does not call drive() in its method body –

Comment: has the error anything to do with creating the objects of a class in the class itself(outside a main method),I have'nt seen such an example before,is it legal..thanks in advance

Comment: I think Brian Roach has the answer you're looking for: the Polo is a subclass of your Car and the default constructor will create a new instance of a Polo again. (since it calls the constructor of Car every time a new instance is created)

Answer (score 4):

```
Car() {
    c[0] = new Polo();
    i=0;
}
```

As Polo is a subclass of *Car()* - it must be to fit in the *Car[]* - it will call the *Car*'s constructor when being constructed itself. The *Car* constructor tries to create a new *Polo()*.

As Polo is a subclass of *Car()* - it must be to fit in the *Car[]* - it will call the *Car*'s constructor when being constructed itself. The *Car* constructor tries to create a new *Polo()*.

As Polo is a subclass of *Car()* - it must be to fit in the *Car[]* - it will call the *Car*'s constructor when being constructed itself. The *Car* constructor tries to create a new *Polo()*.

... you get the picture?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might have some infinite recursion happening.

`drive()` calls `testdrive()` which `class drive()` which calls `testdriver()`...forever, or until you run out of memory, hence your stack overflow error.

Comment: i have edited it,I am sorry the code was not clear but testdrive() does not call drive() in its method body

Comment: has the error anything to do with creating the objects of a class in the class itself(outside a main method),I have'nt seen such an example before,is it legal..thanks in advance