# stackoverflow error when creating object outside the main method

Tags: java, stack-overflow

While running this code it shows Stackoverflow error. What is it I am doing wrong, why does the code compile?

```
public class Foo {
    int a = 5;
    Foo f = new Foo();

    void go() {
        System.out.println(f.a);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo f2 = new Foo();
        f2.go();
    }
}
```

Comment: The stack trace should probably tell you.

Comment: Object orientated view: a Foo that contains a Foo that contains a Foo that contains a Foo that contains a ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `go` method with an instance only. so before call to go started, c'tor has run for class `Foo`

Now, C'tor is designed to initialize all instance members.

So one by one it initializes:

> a is initialized to 5
>
> f is initialized to an Object // but here is the catch, f never gets initilized.

before `=` operator works, C'tor is called and thus the chain continues.

If you see the stacktrace, it'll have `init` written in it. so it's failing during initialization only.

Answer (score 7):

```
Foo f=new Foo();
```

You create an instance of `Foo`, with a variable which itself is an instance of `Foo`, and initialize it in the constructor.

This causes infinite recursion of constructor invokations, untill your stack is out of space.

Answer (score 4):

It's your `f` initializer:

```
public class Foo {
    int a=5;
    Foo f=new Foo();
```

Whenever a new `Foo` is constructed, as part of it's initialization, it attempts to create a `Foo` and assign it to `f`. But obviously, constructing that `Foo` starts the whole process again.

Answer (score 3):

When your program execution starts, control enters to the main method, and finds Foo f2=new Foo(). It creates object of Foo and while creating object it has to instantiate all its instance variables which includes Foo f=new Foo(), so it again creates a new Foo object and loads all instance variables in that and there also it finds same Foo f=new Foo(), so it again creates the Foo object and this will continue until the stack is overflowed.

This can be solved just by changing
    Foo f=new Foo();
to
    Foo f=null;

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a repost of your [question from an hour ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124733/stackoverflow-error). Please take the time to understand the answers people give you.

Your code is the same as:

```
public class Foo {
    Foo f = null;

    public Foo() {
        this.f = new Foo(); // recursion here
    }

    //do your other stuff

}
```

}