# android: DrawerLayout+PagerView=stackOverflow.Why?

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I'd like my app to have side menu with several states with smooth transitions between them.In order to do this I set `PagerView` instance as navigation drawer.My activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="net.rhyboo.com.drawer_test.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>

<net.rhyboo.com.drawer_test.PuzzlePagerView
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+id/pager">
</net.rhyboo.com.drawer_test.PuzzlePagerView>
```

It works well with empty `PagerView`.However if I set adapter for `PagerView`I got stack overflow exception.Here is my activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    DrawerLayout drawer=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    drawer.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gameMenuDim));
    PuzzlePagerView pager=(PuzzlePagerView)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    GameMenuPagerAdapter menuAdapter=new GameMenuPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(menuAdapter);
}
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class GameMenuPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private GameMenuFragment gameMenu;
public GameMenuPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    gameMenu=new GameMenuFragment();
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Log.d("pager",position+"");
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return gameMenu;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 1;
}
}
```

ViewPager:

```
package net.rhyboo.com.drawer_test;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
public class PuzzlePagerView extends ViewPager {
private boolean touchEnabled;
public PuzzlePagerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.touchEnabled) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.touchEnabled) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.touchEnabled = enabled;
}
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class GameMenuFragment extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.game_menu,container);
}
}
```

Stack trace:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: net.rhyboo.com.drawer_test, PID: 14588
                                                                            java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
    at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:6274)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:6278)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:6278)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:6278)

....

Comment: Can you provide PuzzlePagerView / the GameMenuFragment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stackoverflow error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124733/stackoverflow-error)

Comment: At first glance my guess is your issue is inside `GameMenuFragment`, like @Submersed suggested, can you post the code for those classes?

Comment: added pagerView and fragment classes to the initial post

Comment: If I change container parameter in the fragment view inflation to `null` the  error goes away, but in this case it doesn't add my layout to view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was is how I inflate fragment view
instead of

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.game_menu,container);
```

should be

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.game_menu,container,false);
```

I thought it doesn't add my layout to view hierarchy,but it was due to layout was empty=>no visible clues it's there